# Searching for a non-numeric value in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using VBA in Excel to try and write some macros, however, I am very new to the process.

At the moment, I am trying to use a for loop to search a column for a non-numeric value. To do this I wrote the following:

```
rwcnt = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To rwcnt
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = Not IsNumeric Then
        Cells(i, 1).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Exit For
    End If
```

This is returning an error saying that the argument is not optional and it highlights IsNumeric.

What I'd like to accomplish is to search column A and select the first cell that contains non-numeric characters in it outside of my headers. Also, this is searching through >100K cells so if there is a less intensive way to do this process, suggestions would also be nice.

Any help would be appreciated and again, I don't know much at all about this stuff so if everything is wrong, feel free to say so.

Comment: IsNumeric is a function to test an expression, find answer below in few secs! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below code should work fine, note how I have used IsNumeric

```
Sub t()
rwcnt = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To rwcnt
    If Not (IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1).Value)) Then
        range(Cells(i, 1).address, Cells(i, 1).End(xlDown).address).Select
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Also you dont need all of them select's, the above achieves the same result

Comment: Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 2):

`IsNumeric()` is a function to test an expression, so it should be used like this :

```
rwcnt = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To rwcnt
    If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1).Value) <> True Then
        Cells(i, 1).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

When in VBA Editor, press F2 to see Object Browser to get info on functions and press F1 to open Help on that specific function! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help !

Comment: If this solved your issue, please accept answer to mark your question as answered (tick under the up/down vote, on the top-left of each post)